# Nginx load balancer not working as expected when using Docker Compose

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask

I have a simple Flask application that runs on port 5000 that I want to scale up to 3 instances. I want the Nginx load balancer to balance clients based on their associated key provided in the url (i.e. "localhost/get?key=1" will always route to server 1 and "...key=2" always routes to server 2). However, when I use docker-compose to build and scale my app, it is using the Round Robin load balancing strategy instead of the
`hash $arg_key consistent` strategy I have specified in the nginx.conf file.
I am not sure why this is happening.

nginx.conf:

```
events {}

http {
    # Define the group of servers available
 
    upstream backend {
        hash $arg_key consistent;
        server app:5000;
    }
    server {
        # Server group will respond to port 80
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
 
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: components
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
            - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        networks:
            - kvnetwork
    nginx:
        build:
            context: nginx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - './nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            - kvnetwork
        depends_on:
            - app
networks:
    kvnetwork:
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: To me, it looks like you're only running 1 instance of the `app` service.